# ReferenceError: window is undefined even when "use client" is used in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Why does this hook run on the server if `"use client"` is added? It doesn't cause the application to crash, everything works as the error doesn't exist, it just logs the error mentioned in the title at the `const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);` line on the `window` object.

(v13.4.13)

```
"use client";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useWindowWidth = (delay = 100): number => {
  const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);

  useEffect(() => {
    ...
  }, []);

  return windowWidth;
};

export default useWindowWidth;
```

This is from the official [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components#using-client-components-in-nextjs):

> Using Client Components in Next.js
>
> To use Client Components, you can
> add the React "use client" directive at the top of a file, above your
> imports.
>
> "use client" is used to declare a boundary between a Server and Client
> Component modules. This means that by defining a "use client" in a
> file, all other modules imported into it, including child components,
> are considered part of the client bundle - and will be rendered by
> React on the client.

Comment: Avoid not doing stuff on the server side by using `if (typeof window !== 'undefined')`

Answer (score 1):

Client components are rendered on the client (Browser), but before that it's pre-rendered to html at the server in whitch it called SSR Server Side Rendering.

During the SSR, there is neither `window` nor `useState` defined.

At your component, You have a `useState` initializedwith `window.innerWidth`. But, there is no `window` at the server. You will get an error complaining that `cannot read property of undefined. reading window`.

How to fix it (opt-out SSR)?

1. Use the window within an effect hook (e.g. `useEffect`, or `useLayoutEffect`). the `useEffect` hook with empty dependency array delays the callback function until the first render is completed.
2. Dynamic import

```
// page.tsx
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const ClientComponent = dynamic(() => import("path/to/your/client/component"), {ssr: false})
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/42319), the `"use client"` only means that it *also* runs on the client. You can use `useEffect` to access the `window` object without any errors.