# Nextjs 13 'use client' components rendering on server anyway with sanity

Tags: next.js, next.js13, sanity

I'm trying to setup simple **Nextjs** application with **Sanity studio**, where Sanity is appended to my Next application, and lives under the route like `/admin`.

The problem is that when I try to access my Sanity studio via this route, it shows the "forever loading" state without throwing any error.
[image]
As far as I know, in order for Sanity to work this way, the component has to be rendered on the client.
And when I try to print something to the console, it prints out in my terminal, meaning that this component was rendered on the server. And I don't understand why this happens.
[image]

I'm fairly new to Nextjs, but in previous app I didn't have such issue and server components and client components were working just fine.

Here is my `Studio` component code:

```js
"use client";

import { FC } from 'react';
import { NextStudio } from 'next-sanity/studio';

import sanityConfig from '@/sanity.config';

const Studio: FC = () => {
  console.log(`
  -- Sanity studio component with "use client";
  `)
  return <NextStudio config={sanityConfig}/>
}

export default Studio;
```

Here is `Admin` component under `app/admin/[[...index]/page.tsx`:

```js
"use client";

import Studio from '@/src/components/Studio/Studio';

const Admin = () => {
  console.log(`
  -- Admin component with in page.tsx with "use client";
  `);
  return <Studio />;
}

export default Admin;
```

And even if I use `useState` hook which should force the component to be rendered on the client it still renders on the server.

So far I've tried different setups with components, `export default function` and `export default` arrow function as it was mentioned on couple other threads, none of this works.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77111853/18079514

Comment: Thank you for your comment, and I don't think it does as in my previous Nextjs app I was able to print to the browser console with client components and now I can't for some reason.

Comment: Any client component in Next.js is rendered firstly on the server.

Comment: I understand that, but even that, the client components should print to the browser console, and in this case they doesn't.